# Passing arbitrary column values to D3 visualization when reading data file

Tags: d3.js

I am using the D3 histogram visualization and want to pass headers in that are not necessarily named "letter" or "frequency."  If I attempt to change the column attributes in the following block of code then no visualization shows. How can I pass in arbitrary column names?

```
d3.tsv(datapath, type, function(error, data) {
               x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
               y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
```

Comment: you cannot reference column names that are not in your data set. what is the reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: the column names would be/are in the dataset. In the example above the column names must be "letter" and "frequency."

Comment: If the column names have spaces try d["some col"]....also make sure that numeric columns are numeric and not text. You can check this by printing your data to the console.

Comment: But thats not an arbitrary column name. Arbitrary means the column name acts like a variable and can be changed at run time.

Comment: ok so if it doesn't have quote around it and you just use the variable then it works.  Thank you. If you want the answer points go ahead and post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets allow the passing of variables.

```
d3.tsv(datapath, type, function(error, data) {
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d[columnname1]; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[columnname2]; })]);
```